# Using Devel-Cover to get coverage reports

Tags: perl, code-coverage, devel-cover

I am new to Perl and I am trying to generate a coverage report for a Perl script I had. I followed the steps mentioned here to install Devel-Cover https://code.activestate.com/ppm/Devel-Cover/ and ran

```
perl -MDevel::Cover script
```

I get some coverage info and that message

```
    Pod coverage is unavailable.  Please install Pod::Coverage from CPAN.
```

Then running command `cover` to generate the report I get `cover: Command not found.` Tring to run `cpan install Pod::Coverage` as stated by the output but it fails. I am not sure what I am missing here.
I tried using Devel::Coverage too using

```
 perl -d:Coverage script
```

But I got that output

```
Can't locate Devel/Coverage.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Devel::Coverage module) (@INC contains: /spiratech/tools/perllib /home/mmaher/.cache/activestate/02540130/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.32.0/x86_64-linux /home/mmaher/.cache/activestate/02540130/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.32.0 /home/mmaher/.cache/activestate/02540130/lib/perl5/5.32.0/x86_64-linux /home/mmaher/.cache/activestate/02540130/lib/perl5/5.32.0).
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
%!s(<nil>)
```

and I couldn't find any instructions on how to install it. I am using Perl v5.32.0

Comment: Which version of Windows (I assume you are in Windows since you mentioned Active State) are you using? How did you install perl itself?

Comment: I am using a Centos 7 machine.

Comment: Ok I didn't realize that you could use ActivePerl on Linux. Anyway, how did you install `perl` itself and how did you install `Devel::Cover` ?

Comment: In the tutorial I was following for installation it didn't say it's working on Windows only and I found an ActiveState version for Linux which I installed. Am I missing something?

Comment: Ok! I'll then have to test ActivePerl on Linux first. I come back to you later.

Comment: Hi @Merolla, I have tested now on Ubuntu 21.04, and it works for me. Before I downloaded the ActivePerl build, I added (Add packages) the `Devel-Cover` package, then I downloaded the `.tar.gz` build, extracted it. And then run `sh install.sh` and installed into my home directory at `/home/hakon/activeperl/5.28`. I added `/home/hakon/activeperl/5.28/site/bin:/home/hakon/activeperl/5.28/bin` to my `PATH` variable, when I now type `which cover` it shows that the command `cover` is located in `/home/hakon/activeperl/5.28/bin/cover`. Further I can install `Pod::Coverage` by running...

Comment: ... `cpan Pod::Coverage`

Comment: I reinstalled ActivePerl using the steps you stated and added it to the path, but I didn't find neither the command cover  nor ppm to run ppm install Devel-Cover in the new installation.

Comment: *"to run ppm install Devel-Cover in the new installation"* You do not need to install Devel::Cover if you added the package before downloading. Anyway, can you try `cpan` instead of `ppm` to install the package (provided you did not add the package before downloading ActivePerl) ? Try run `cpan Devel::Cover` from the command prompt.

Comment: Also: What is the output of `perl --version` ? And `which perl` ?

Comment: I ran `cpan Devel::Cover` using the new installation but running `perl -MDevel::Cover script` kept failing. I tried using Perl from the old installation of ActivePerl I had and running the script and cover worked just fine from that installation. I am not sure which step exactly fixed the issue. Thanks a lot for your help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Zeroth, ActiveState's PPM is old stuff. They have a new [State Tool](https://www.activestate.com/blog/goodbye-ppm-hello-state-tool/) to handle all of that. Note that this is for using their Perl packages. If you aren't using ActiveState's perl, don't use their instructions.

First, you only need Pod::Coverage if you want to check that all of your public subroutines are documented. It's an optional feature.

Second, there's no `install` command to `cpan`. Just list the modules that you want or use the command line options. With no options, the `-i` (for install) is assumed:

```
$ cpan Pod::Coverage
$ cpan -i Pod::Coverage
```

Third, the `-d` switch for debugging assumes that you are loading a module under the `Devel` namespace. That's why `-d:Coverage` looks for `Devel::Coverage`, which it then cannot find.

To load any module that you like, you can use the `-M` switch. This takes the entire module name:

```
$ perl -MPod::Coverage
```

Lastly, once you install `Devel::Cover`, look where you installed `cover` and ensure that that directory is in your `PATH`.